# Excluding certain Log.i messages in IntelliJ / LogCat?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, logcat

My error log gets cluttered with "Grow heap" messages and I was wondering if I could either filter out those messages, or alternatively *only* display those that *I've* created?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using eclipse you can filter your logcat output. for example show only logs from your application or with a specific tag. you can define several filter.

it's easier to use it that way, than implementing an own 'custom log logic'

[image]

i'm not sure about excluding, but at least you can only show logs from your application